Creating copies of original lists in Python
I have 5 lists containing data: List_1, List_2, List_3, List_4, List_5
I want to perform an analysis to each of these lists, but also keep the original lists as a reference for later so I can compare them. This is relatively easy to do since I only have 5 lists:
New_list_1 = List_1
New_list_2 = List_2
New_list_3 = List_3
New_list_4 = List_4
New_list_5 = List_5

I am aware that I could also make like a "list of lists" List = [List_1, List_2, List_3...] but then I would still have the problem of having to do, which is not shorter:
New_list_1 = List[0]
New_list_2 = List[1]
New_list_3 = List[2]
New_list_4 = List[3]
New_list_5 = List[4]

But for future, what if I had like 700 lists? Would it be possible to loop over these numbered lists like this?
for i in range(700):
    New_list_*insert i here somehow* = List_*insert i here somehow*

If this approach is possible, how would I go about attaching i, which is an integer, as string, to a variable name?

Why do you need New_list_1? Why can't you just do New_lists = Lists[:]? If you have a number at the end of your variable name you are most likely making a mistake

None of the examples you showed make a copy of the lists. You just have the same list with two different names.

This may be an xy problem. Are you sure you can’t do the analysis you need without mutating the original lists?

If Lists is a list of lists then, to make a copy, you could do this:
Lists = [List_1, List_2, List_3, List_4, List_5]
New_lists = [e.copy() for e in Lists]

Note that a list's copy() function is shallow

Thank you. This does the trick perfectly and my code runs flawlessly.

Or just use deepcopy from the copy module directly New_Lists = copy.deepcopy(Lists)

@user19077881 Additional module import deliberately avoided for the sake of simplicity


Instead of creating individual variables like New_list_1, New_list_2, etc., you can use a dictionary to store the lists. This allows you to map each list dynamically to a key, where the key can be the list number (e.g., 1, 2, ..., 700), and you can access or modify them easily.

# Example of original lists (List_1, List_2, ..., List_5)

    List_1 = [1, 2, 3]
    List_2 = [4, 5, 6]
    List_3 = [7, 8, 9]
    List_4 = [10, 11, 12]
    List_5 = [13, 14, 15]
    
    # Put your original lists in a dictionary
    
    lists = {
        1: List_1,
        2: List_2,
        3: List_3,
        4: List_4,
        5: List_5
    }
    
     # If you have more lists, you can extend this dynamically or use a loop
     # For example, simulating 700 lists (as an example)
    
        for i in range(1, 701):    
            lists[f"New_list_{i}"] = lists[i].copy()
    
         print(lists['New_list_1'])


Why would you use a dictionary with numeric keys rather than a simple list (which is already indexible by number)?
